# Android: split very large strings

Tags: java, android, split

I have the folowing XML SAX Handler:

```
private class GetXML_Handler extends DefaultHandler {
        int x = 0;
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            Log.i("DataHandler", "Start of XML element");
            int y = 0;
            if (qName.equals("polygon")) {
                locations.add(x, new ArrayList<location>());
                String coordinates = attributes.getValue("coordinates");
                String[] parts = coordinates.split(",");
                System.out.println("Cyklus zacaty");
                locations.get(x).add(y, new location(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]), Double.parseDouble(parts[1])));
                for(int i = 2; i <= parts.length; i = i + 2){
                    y++;
                    double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(parts[i].substring(2));
                    double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(parts[i+1]);
                    locations.get(x).add(y, new location(Latitude, Longitude));
                }
                System.out.println("cyklus skonceny");
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
```

However "cyklus zacaty" never gets printed. It prints okay if I move it before `String[] parts = coordinates.split(",")` . Those strings are rly big (like 350 GPS coordinates) so is it possible that java simply cant handle it and it stops (with no exception).

Also my "Start of XML element" gets printed only 5 times (till first coordinates) but if I remove this split method it prints 28 times (number of my XML elements). I am sure that my XML handler works correctly (its just something about those Strings).

Structure of XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oblasti>
    <oblast>
        <nazovOblasti>VT</nazovOblasti>
        <polygon>
            <coordinates>
               132456,4658789,0 56487,4864684
            </coordinates>
        </polygon>
      ....
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in forward

Comment: well, i can tell you that it is not about the length of the Strings and the split method.

Comment: yeah I realized that when I added only 6 coordinates and it stopped too ... but I cant see where is the problem

Comment: you should use your debugger to see where the programm stops/exits. Or, my favorite, use many System.out.println() to figure out which values are not as expected.

Comment: well I used System.out.println() and it worked correclty before initializing parts = coordinates.split(","). But when I put it just after this line it doesnt print anything

Comment: what about error logs? exceptions? first guess , coordinates is NULL! maybe ?!

Comment: if it's null there should be still thrown a NullPointer.

Comment: @huidube that's why i asked him about error logs

Comment: error log is absolutely clear. No Exceptions are thrown

Comment: I have added XML structure and my actual code. Am I parsing coordinates value correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attributes parameter does not contain the child elements of the node, only the attributes assigned to the node (if any). Hence, `attributes.getValue("coordinates")` is not doing what you expect.

Comment: yeah I edited it and now it is getting texts but still some of this split methods is causing problems

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not with the split method, but this line:

```
locations.get(x).add(y, new location(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]), Double.parseDouble(parts[1])));
```

and the reason is because the string has whitespaces, and they stay after splitted, so it can't be parsed.

try this just after the split and before anything else:

```
for (i=0; i<parts.length(); i++){
parts[i].trim();
}
```

when an exception occurs, sometimes it breaks the thread before last line is completely executed, especially if it's a console output. It has made me mad too many times. This may be the reason your printline doesn't show.

Comment: also, he got Strings like: "0 56487" (he posted in the XML file), which will rise an NumberFormatException.. But this still doesnt explain, why he is not getting any Errors. And as discussed before: He dont even reach the first System.out.println(); So the problem has to be somewhere else. (note, that the problem you described will also occure)

Comment: True. He has to control that too. But I think somehow the exception is not showing but still raises.

Comment: made an edit to my original post (edited xml structure)... I have no whitespaces before or after commas so no need to trim and I am controling this "0 56487" by using substring(2) on every second item

Comment: you have to tell us where the programm is exiting. put a breakpoint to line " if (qName.equals("polygon")) {" and go through it with the debugger line by line.

Comment: Have you printed on console the "coordinates" string? Maybe it has something you didn't control

Comment: the problem was that I had new line after coordinates and it couldnt read it ... I am close to solution now ... will post afterwards

Comment: So now I can easily load first set of coordinates but afterwards I get IndexOutOfBounds exception with second set but it is loading coordinates string just as it is expected

Comment: that part is easy, look in your loop, and remove the "=" in "i <= parts.length()" (Line 12). Length is always one more than last index, so if loop doesn't stop before, it reaches one more than last index and it raises exception